# A Kindle question closed; why? It's software+hardware...

Tags: support, close-reasons, reopen-request, user-interface, software

https://superuser.com/q/276010/65570 was closed with a message "Questions on Super User are expected to generally relate to computer software or computer hardware in some way".

According to the quoted message the closed question appears to be completel on-topic. So it must stay open on the site.

More detailed argument:

The question is about the software running on this piece of hardware -- Amazon Kindle. Is Kindle off-topic? Probably not, because we even have a tag for it here.

> Can the software be configured/updated to have a Russian UI?

Please re-open.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in the SU faq:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts
>   and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> > -computer hardware
> >
> > -computer software
>
> and it is **not about** …
>
> > -**electronic devices**, media players, cell phones or smart phones, **except
> >     insofar as they interface with your
> >     computer**

The question does not reference anything related to the Kindle and a computer interacting per se. It is an **electronic device**.

Comment: Thanks, now I see the reason.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not a Stack Exchange site that would be appropriate. There was "Gadgets" but it was shut down because it was too broad. There is, however, an [Area 51 proposal for e-Books and e-Book Readers](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20794/e-books-and-e-book-readers) that you might help get off the ground.

Comment: I've gotta say, I disagree with this. The Kindle has a web browser and you can, at least in theory, use it as a general-use device. (For example, you could use it for email and word processing.)

Comment: @neilfein We don't consider iPads, Android tablet computers and smart phones to be "computers" like the FAQ requires, and they're (AFAIK) much more versatile than Kindles.